# ¿Cómo guardar solo los valores seleccionados (Checkbox)?

Tags: javascript, html, array

```
<input type="checkbox" name="webcampics[]" class="webcampics" value="1"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="webcampics[]" class="webcampics" value="2"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="webcampics[]" class="webcampics" value="3"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="webcampics[]" class="webcampics" value="4"/>
```

Al ejecutar la función me guarda los 4 `checkbox` en la variable `for2` aunque yo solo haya seleccionado 1 o 2 etc.

```
function compra(){
         var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName( 'webcampics' ),
        for2  = [].map.call(inputs, function( input ) {
            return input.value;
        }).join( '-' );
       VentanaCentrada('./pdf/documentos/ordendecompra_pdf.php?for2='+for2+,'Cotizacion','','1024','768','true');

    };
```

Necesito que solo guarde los `checkbox` marcados en la variable `for2`

Answer (score 1):

Te recoge todos porque recorres los elementos por la clase, no preguntas si están o no seleccionados.

Para ver si están seleccionados con `jquery`:

```
var escogidos = $('input[name=webcampics[]]:checked');

escogidos.each(function(){
}
```

En tu código sería algo así (teniendo jquery):

```
  function compra(){
      var escogidos = $('input[name=webcampics[]]:checked');
      for2 = "";
        escogidos.each(function(){
          for2 = for2 + $this.val() + "-";
        }
        VentanaCentrada('./pdf/documentos/ordendecompra_pdf.php?for2='+for2+,'Cotizacion','','1024','768','true');
}
```

Comment: aaaaaa y como uno eso a mi codigo ya lo intente y no puedo :C

Comment: No funciono :C muchas gracias  igual

Answer (score 0):

```
function compra(){
 var inputs = $('input:checkbox:checked');
    for2  = [].map.call(inputs, function( input ) {
        return input.value;
    }).join( '-' );   

  var cotiza = $("#cotiza").val();
    var atencion = $("#atencion").val();
  var empresa = $("#empresa").val();
  VentanaCentrada('./pdf/documentos/ordendecompra_pdf.php?cotiza='+cotiza+'&for2='+for2+'&atencion='+atencion+'&empresa='+empresa,'Cotizacion','','1024','768','true');

};
```

de esa manera lo resolví :D por si a alguien lo llegase a nesesitar

Comment: y como para que los valla guardando pero en el orden que se seleccionan los check?